# Why does Cargo incorrectly compile Rust WASM global variables?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, rust-wasm

The following Rust compiled to WASM, based on the [Wasmer exports_global.rs WASM example](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/blob/master/examples/exports_global.rs), produces incorrect WASM (with `cargo build --target=wasm32-wasi`):

```
// (module
//     (global $one (export "one") f32 (f32.const 1))
//     (global $some (export "some") (mut f32) (f32.const 0))

//     (func (export "get_one") (result f32) (global.get $one))
//     (func (export "get_some") (result f32) (global.get $some))

//     (func (export "set_some") (param f32) (global.set $some (local.get 0))))

#[no_mangle]
pub static one: f32 = 1.0;

#[no_mangle]
pub static mut some: f32 = 0.0;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_one() -> f32 {
    one
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_some() -> f32 {
    unsafe { some }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn set_some(value: f32) {
    unsafe {
        some = value;
    }
}
```

Inspecting the compiled module, I get:

```
 wasmer inspect .\target\wasm32-wasi\debug\rust_wasm.wasm
Type: wasm
Size: 2.1 MB
Imports:
  Functions:
  Memories:
  Tables:
  Globals:
Exports:
  Functions:
    "get_one": [] -> [F32]
    "get_some": [] -> [F32]
    "set_some": [F32] -> []
  Memories:
    "memory": not shared (17 pages..)
  Tables:
  Globals:
    "some": I32 (constant)
    "one": I32 (constant)
```

Specifically, the `Globals` are wrong. They should both be `F32` and `some` should be mutable. Why is this happening?

Comment: Sure that's the **value** of those variables and not the **initialization**?

Comment: AFAIK that's telling me the globals are an `I32` type but according to my declaration they should be `F32`. The example has an assert on the type and that fails because `I32 != F32`.

Comment: I can't find any proof for that right now, but it seems that statics in WASM are exported by-address, not by-value, and the address in WASM linear memory is `i32`.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the commented out WebAssembly Text, also in the link, and associated program runs with directly accessing globals as their F32 type, but in Rust compiled to WASM, something different happens.